# Is it possible to import a text file into a sqlite table with php?

Tags: php, sqlite, import, text-files

I am creating a program which requires me to insert large amounts of data into a table. The data is already saved in a text file so obviously would be quicker to use some code to insert the data into the tables.

I have done research on how this can be done with sqlite but haven't found any answers, some people have said it isnt possible to import with sqlite. Apologies for no code specifically for the import as I dont know where to start.

This is the table I want the data to go into:

```
$db->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "weekData" (
    "week1" INTEGER,
    "week2" INTEGER,
    "week3" INTEGER,
    "week4" INTEGER
)');
```

The data will be used for various tasks such as creating a histogram. Thanks! :)

Comment: SQLite has tools to import CSV data into a table : http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-import-csv/
Depending of the original format of your text file, maybe it is acceptable to convert it into CSV, and then use the import tool.

Comment: Thanks! When converting my text file into csv, all my row data goes into 1 column instead of 4. Can one column in the csv still reference 4 rows in sqlite? @JoffreySchmitz

Comment: One column in CSV cannot be imported as 4 rows in SQLite, if that's what you are asking @TheBiz

Comment: In CSV, the columns are separated by a comma per default. Make sure it is the case in your CSV file. Maybe it is possible to set an option if you have a different character as separator.